# Unable to route to webserver

Tags: windows, web-server

Hi I'm trying to open a port in my windows 7 machine, use wampserver and use dlinkddns to try and forward requests to reach my server.

But I'm having a bit of problem trying to get that to work.

First of all I opened port 55555 in my firewall to allow connections, then as you all may have guessed, I'm using a dlink DVG-G5402SP voIP router, and set up a virtual server with port 55555 opened there.

So i'm wondering what else is hindering me from trying to set up a connection for my friends to my webserver.

I have used netsh to verify that port 55555 is opened.

I also used PFPortChecker but saw that the port cannot be reached by them.. I hope you guys can provide some assistance. Thanks

Comment: I saw this exact post this morning but it was deleted (http://serverfault.com/questions/226720/port-unable-to-reach). Did you just repost this to bump it? That's frowned on here.

Comment: I deleted that post as I thought at I solved it. I didnt know that within my own network, all of it is working, while given my friends all could not see it. Sorry for re-posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your router to do [Port-Forwarding](http://portforward.com/). Else no one outside you LAN will be able to get througth the router. There you need to also configure the right IP address of you computer. So for virtual server not only the port is important but also the IP address the packages should be 'routed' to.

Comment: I have set a static IP for my machine, 192.168.8.150, and I have set a virtual server, which is equivalent of port forwarding using a dlink router, I've also tried port filtering, dmz but to no avail.
the port when viewed from the router's config, is opened, but the actual data does not get through.

Comment: You could use OnlinePortscanners (i.e. http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/) to check if the port is open from the outside too. You should disable the DMZ!